# MySQL in Python, MATCH and injection attack

Tags: python, mysql, sql-injection, match

1. Is `MATCH` from MySQL also vulnerable to injection attack?
   For example:

   ```
   """SELECT * 
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE MATCH(myColumnName) AGAINST(%s) 
        ORDER BY id 
        LIMIT 20""" % query
   ```

   seems to allow arbitrary strings, which looks bad.
2. If so, I've instead tried - following examples in the Python docs -

   ```
   t = (query,)
   statement = """SELECT * 
                    FROM myTable 
                    WHERE MATCH(myColumnName) AGAINST(?) 
                    ORDER BY id 
                    LIMIT 20"""
   cursor.execute(statement, t)
   ```

   but nothing is returned - even when the string `query` returned hits in (1) above. Why is that?
3. In 2), using the placeholder `%s` instead of `?` returns results. Why is this safer than 1) (if at all)? E.g. with the query string I can always close off a string and parenthesis with `query=')...'` and continue `query=') OR otherColumnName LIKE '%hello%' --`.

Therefore, is it enough to strip query strings of everything but roman characters or numerals?

Comment: Using prepared query like above - with `?` makes sure the strings are treated as quoted/escaped when needed.

Comment: The [sample](http://sscce.org/) isn't complete. In 2., what's the value of `query`? What's a row you expect it to match? Note that while it doesn't matter in samples, don't use [`SELECT *`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select) in production code; select only the columns you need.

Comment: As it happens, I need all of the columns in the table. I could spell this out equivalently by naming all of the columns.

Comment: Do you need all the columns that may be in the table now and in the future, or only the columns when the SQL statement was written? What happens if you have to add columns? Take a closer look at the question regarding `SELECT *` linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: I only need the columns that are present today, I may or may not need future ones. Therefore I went with replacing '*' by the individual column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't much matter what operators, functions, clauses or any other [host-language](http://blog.oudamou.co.cc/2011/07/programmatic-mutualism.html) terms you're using when it comes to injection. Injection is a matter of mixing data and language statements, which happens when you interpolate data into a statement. Prepared statement parameters keep data and statements separate, so they're not vulnerable to injection.

As for `?` versus `%s` for parameters, the MySQLdb documentation for [Cursor.execute](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#execute) says the following:

> `execute(self, query, args=None)`
>
> [...]
>
> Note: If args is a sequence, then %s must be used as the parameter placeholder in the query. If a mapping is used, %(key)s must be used as the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

When using a parameterized statement with arguments, MySQLdb escapes the arguments and uses Python string formating to re-insert those arguments into the parametrized statement. A single string statement is then sent to the server. 
You are relying on MySQLdb's ability to properly escape arguments to protect against SQL injection:

MySQLdb/cursors.py:

```
def execute(self, query, args=None):
    ...
    if args is not None:
        query = query % db.literal(args)
```

In contrast, [oursql sends queries and data to the server completely separately](http://packages.python.org/oursql/tutorial.html#executing-queries).
It does not rely on escaping the data. This should be even safer.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is not correct since it uses basic python string formatting, that will not escape the query string.

The second method is the preferred method of sending a simple query to the server and it will properly escape the query.

You just have a simple bug. You need to replace `AGAINST(?)` with `AGAINST(%s)`

The information is also found in the python [DbApi FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DbApiFaq)

Comment: Python MySQL won't accept `?` as a placeholder here for a string at all?

Comment: the `paramstyle` parameter of `connect` should be able to set what the formating expects

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes it's enough to sanitise the `query` string - strip if of all non-alphanumeric characters (in particular `'` and `)`).